# How to prevent onRowClicked when using a cellRenderer in AgGridReact

Tags: ag-grid-react, cellrenderer

When using your own **cell renderer** for e.g. an **action column** - with links or buttons in it -, AgGridReact still triggers a `onRowClicked` event when you click on one of the links or buttons. `event.stopPropagation` and `event.preventDefault` do not help.

```
// list of rowActions ...

function RowActionsRenderer(props) {
        let row = props.data;
        return <div>{
            rowActions.map((actionDef, index) =>
                <Button onClick={(event) => {
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    event.preventDefault();
                    //_processAction(actionDef, row)
                }}>{label(actionDef.name)}</Button>
            )
        }</div>;
    }
```

Definition of cellRenderer:

```
// ...
columnDefs.push({
                headerName: 'actions',
                field: '-actions-',
                width: 120,
                sortable: false,
                filter: false,
                cellRenderer: 'rowActionsRenderer'
            });


// ...
            frameworkComponents: {
                rowActionsRenderer: RowActionsRenderer
            },
```

Registration of event listening:

```
             onRowClicked={(row) => {
                        // always runs event when when clicked on button in the '-actions-' column !!!
                    }}
```

Now, how do you prevent `onRowClicked` being called when clicking anything in the '-actions-'  column?

Answer (score 0):

There are some rather complicated low level calls to the AgGrid api I like to avoid.
So my proposed solution would be:

First, do not listen to row clicks.

Second listen to cell clicks and filter out column id `'-actions-'`

```
onCellClicked={(cell) => {

                                if (cell.column.getColId() === '-actions-') {
                                    return;
                                }
                                let row = cell.data;
                                // process row data ...
                                
                            }
```